# On Jenkins, is there a way to give permissions to users per folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

On Jenkins, I want to bring permissions to users per folder.
We currently have jobs under "VIEW"
-It's not to grant permissions at the VIEW level, it is possible at the folder level
-Job under a folder causes the job name to change

*The current situation is not good for us because if someone wants to create a new job / change configuration etc. it requires permissions on the whole Jenkins because Jenkins does not allow to give permissions to the user according to VIEW.

-> The mission is basically to turn the VIEW at Jenkins into FOLDERS so we can give permissions to the development team so they can leave us alone.

What is the best and safest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem the simplest solution is to install the [Folders plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder/), move the jobs to folders and use the [Folder-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-auth/). We use the mode advanced [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) as our installation predates the availability of the Folder-based plugin.

Views can be created which recurse folders, so they can see the jobs they are entitled to, where they belong.

There is also an ( `{JENKINS_URL}/configure` ) option :

`[ X ] Restrict project naming`

which is extended to
`(o) Role-Based Strategy`

to constrain naming of jobs.

btw: as detailed in this [SuperUser response](https://superuser.com/a/1509747/497981), a job only has one real fullName (path), notwithstanding the `/view/` url.

Comment: Hey , tnx for the deateiled answer! Thing is I'm talking about moving a mass of jobs -each under an other view(but all together under one collective view).
Other issue is the problem that I'll have to manage permissions per folder and it will not help because it will transfer the management of the groups to us and it should stay in AD

Comment: Sorry it won't let me edit anymore -- Hey, thanks for the detailed answer! The thing is, I'm talking about moving a mass of jobs (and GitHub repositories) - each under a separate view (but all together under one collective view).
The other issue is the problem that I'll have to manage permissions per folder and it will not help because it will transfer the management of the groups to us and it should stay in the active directory.